# How to toggle on/off timer programmatically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, function, timer

This is what I want to do:
I want a timer, to fire a method and then, in the end of this method, be toggled off, and turn on an other timer on another method, and then entering a loop.

So what are the codes used to toggle between on and off the timer on a method?

In Delphi I use:

```
timer.enable:=True; // timer.enable:=False;
```

Are there a similar way to do it on objective-c?
I'm using Xcode 4.4
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To turn the timer off, call `invalidate` on your timer like so:

`[yourTimer invalidate]`

And then to start a new one:

```
NSTimer *newTimer;

                     newTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 //Every how many seconds
                                                                target:self
                                                              selector:@selector(methodToCall)
                                                              userInfo:nil
                                                               repeats:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your NSTimer is called "timer", you can use...

```
[timer invalidate]
```

to stop the timer.  To make a timer pass a message to it's target method instantly, use

```
[timer fire]
```

To start a timer, you use one of the constructor methods listed in the documentation (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nstimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html) such as

```
NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(doThisWhenTimerFires:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO]

- (void)doThisWhenTimerFires:(NSTimer *)timer
{
     //code here
}
```